# How to get pointer to data in struct via getElementPtr? (in the llvm package)

Tags: haskell, llvm

I'm trying to create a struct and access elements in it in llvm via the [llvm-3.0.0.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-3.0.0.0) package on ghc 7.4.1 and am running into some hairy types. Here's a sample code, I'm trying to get the structure's second element (i.e. the `Word32` in TestStruct.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
import LLVM.Core
import Data.Word

type TestStruct = Struct (Word16 :& Word32 :& Word64)
getTestPtr :: Value (Ptr TestStruct) -> CodeGenFunction r (Value (Ptr Word32))
getTestPtr u = getElementPtr u (0 :: Word32, (1  :: Word32, ()))
```

But I get the following error on ghc 7.4.1:

```
Test.hs:8:16:
    Overlapping instances for llvm-3.0.0.0:LLVM.Core.Instructions.GetField
                                (Word32, Word64) i Word32
      arising from a use of `getElementPtr'
    Matching instances:
      instance [overlap ok] (llvm-3.0.0.0:LLVM.Core.Instructions.GetField
                               as i b,
                             Succ i i') =>
                            llvm-3.0.0.0:LLVM.Core.Instructions.GetField (a, as) i' b
        -- Defined in `llvm-3.0.0.0:LLVM.Core.Instructions'
      instance [overlap ok] llvm-3.0.0.0:LLVM.Core.Instructions.GetField
                              (a, as) D0 a
        -- Defined in `llvm-3.0.0.0:LLVM.Core.Instructions'
    (The choice depends on the instantiation of `i'
     To pick the first instance above, use -XIncoherentInstances
     when compiling the other instance declarations)
    In the expression: getElementPtr u (0 :: Word32, (0 :: Word32, ()))
    In an equation for `getTestPtr':
        getTestPtr u = getElementPtr u (0 :: Word32, (0 :: Word32, ()))

Test.hs:8:16:
    No instances for (Data.TypeLevel.Num.Sets.PosI Word32,
                      Data.TypeLevel.Num.Ops.IsZero Word32 yz,
                      DivMod10 Word32 yi yl)
      arising from a use of `getElementPtr'
    Possible fix:
      add instance declarations for
      (Data.TypeLevel.Num.Sets.PosI Word32,
       Data.TypeLevel.Num.Ops.IsZero Word32 yz,
       DivMod10 Word32 yi yl)
    In the expression: getElementPtr u (0 :: Word32, (0 :: Word32, ()))
    In an equation for `getTestPtr':
        getTestPtr u = getElementPtr u (0 :: Word32, (0 :: Word32, ()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing into a `Struct` in the `llvm` package requires type level numbers so the field type can be computed statically. This is the reason for the nested tuple that describes the record fields. If you use `getElementPtr` the first index value needs to be a regular integer (`Word32` or whatever), or just use `getElementPtr0` instead.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
import LLVM.Core
import Data.TypeLevel
import Data.Word

type TestStruct = Struct (Word16 :& Word32 :& Word64)
getTestPtr :: Value (Ptr TestStruct) -> CodeGenFunction r (Value (Ptr Word32))
-- getTestPtr u = getElementPtr u ((0 :: Word32) & d1 & ())
getTestPtr u = getElementPtr0 u (d1 & ())
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
I did notice that GetField typeclass demanded a type level number,
but I was trying `(undefined :: D1)` and getting some other errors.

I do not see `d1` in [type-level haddock documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level-0.2.4), neither on Hayoo.

Comment: @Chetan I'd guess hackage is using an older/buggy version of haddock. My locally built docs show `d0` in `Data.TypeLevel.Num.Aliases`. Though I would figure `undefined :: D0` would work just as well..